# Can''t find the right ethernet library in Arduino IDE for Arduino Nano RP2040 Connect

Tags: arduino-ide

Searching revealed there is a library for the ethernet chip onboard for Arduino Nano RP2040 Connect, and docs say to search for it in the mBed.  I chose the only board id available that was connected. I get the following error when I check the code in the IDE:

/private/var/folders/hc/39cys7xx68s4vd7gxrchyxn80000gn/T/.arduinoIDE-unsaved202285-19994-p3tosu.z75d/sketch_sep5a/sketch_sep5a.ino:2:10: fatal error: WiFiNINA.h: No such file or directory
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Compilation error: WiFiNINA.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I've tried all the examples I can find to make code compile, such as the instructions found here: https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nano-rp2040-connect/rp2040-ap-web-server-rgb - and I always get an error saying it can't find WiFiNINA.h .  How to resolve?  Nothing I can figure out will let me try with success the example code I find online. Please help a total newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version of Arduio IDE (2.0.2 as of now) and install the WiFiNINA library.

[image]
Once the library is installed, re-compile, and the error *"Compilation error: WiFiNINA.h: No such file or directory"* should get resolved.